# get row with same id but different value and display different value into different label asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

this work but i want to display if value exist, so user can see the value username and last_update in each label based on each process_id but they have same request_id. this code only display username and last_update for the one that based on username login only.how i can do that ?

```
 using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MESTrans"].ConnectionString))
        {
            //bool exists = false;
            int exists;
            con.Open();

                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
                {

                    int req_id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView2.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[0]);
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from [CutPanelConfirmation] where req_id=@req_id and process_id=@process_id", con))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@process_id", Session["process_id"].ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@req_id", req_id);
                        exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    }
                    if (exists > 0)
                    {
                        query = "select * from CutPanelConfirmation where req_id=@req_id and process_id=@process_id";
                        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@process_id", Session["process_id"].ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@req_id", req_id);
                        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                       while (dr.Read())
                        {

                            if ((string)dr["process_id"] == "marker")
                            {

                                LabelNameMarker.Text = LabelNameMarker.Text + " " + dr[1].ToString();
                                LabelDateMarker.Text = LabelDateMarker.Text + " " + dr[3].ToString();

                            }
                            if ((string)dr["process_id"] == "fabric")
                            {
                                LabelNameFabric.Text = LabelNameFabric.Text + " " + dr[1].ToString();
                                LabelDateFabric.Text = LabelDateFabric.Text + " " + dr[3].ToString();
                            }
                            if ((string)dr["process_id"] == "cutting")
                            {
                                LabelNameCutting.Text = LabelNameCutting.Text + " " + dr[1].ToString();
                                LabelDateCutting.Text = LabelDateCutting.Text + " " + dr[3].ToString();
                            }
                            if ((string)dr["process_id"] == "SPP")
                            {
                                LabelNameSPP.Text = LabelNameSPP.Text + " " + dr[1].ToString();
                                LabelDateSPP.Text = LabelDateSPP.Text + " " + dr[3].ToString();
                            }
                            if ((string)dr["process_id"] == "kitting")
                            {
                                LabelNameKitting.Text = LabelNameKitting.Text + " " + dr[1].ToString();
                                LabelDateKitting.Text = LabelDateKitting.Text + " " + dr[3].ToString();
                            }
                            if ((string)dr["process_id"] == "sew")
                            {
                                LabelNameSew.Text = LabelNameSew.Text + " " + dr[1].ToString();
                                LabelDateSew.Text = LabelDateSew.Text + " " + dr[3].ToString();
                            }

                        }
                        dr.Close();

                    }

                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: i already got the answer ! thankyou !

Comment: Hi, please could you post your solution as an answer so that other people who find your question can find your solution?

Comment: hai i just delete@process id from this query and it works as what i want! : query = "select * from CutPanelConfirmation where req_id=@req_id and process_id=@process_id";
                        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@process_id", Session["process_id"].ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@req_id", req_id);
                        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Answer (score 0):

posting [https://stackoverflow.com/users/7892938/nfh][NFH] answer 
i just delete@process id from this query and it works as what i want! :

`query = "select * from CutPanelConfirmation where req_id=@req_id and process_id=@process_id"; cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con); cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@process_id", Session["process_id"].ToString()); cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@req_id", req_id); SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();`